# Pattern matching in a list of maps

Tags: elixir, pattern-matching, ecto

I have a nested list of maps, and I would like to grab a specific element of a map. How can I do it?

This is my map:

```
[
%Eagle.Content.TemplateFields.TemplateField{
__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "template_fields">,
id: 13,
inserted_at: ~N[2021-10-20 12:02:42],
name: "Meta title",
name_slug: "meta_title",
position: nil,
settings: %{"options" => [], "validate" => %{"required" => []}},
template: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :template is not loaded>,
template_id: 4,
type: "text",
updated_at: ~N[2021-10-20 12:02:42]
},
%Eagle.Content.TemplateFields.TemplateField{
__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "template_fields">,
id: 14,
inserted_at: ~N[2021-10-20 12:02:42],
name: "Meta description",
name_slug: "meta_description",
position: nil,
settings: %{"options" => [], "validate" => []},
template: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :template is not loaded>,
template_id: 4,
type: "text",
updated_at: ~N[2021-10-20 12:02:42]
 }
]
```

And I would like to get name from second map.

For now I have something like this:
`x = landing_page.template.fields[%{name: "Meta description"}]`

I will be grateful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned Pattern Matching. If you are looking for pattern without using the helper functions in Enum etc.  Then do:

```
[ a | b ] = your_value # your deeply nested data. You can ignore a or b using an _

[ c ] = b # which one you want, the first or second element from your map? I chose the second "b" from above.

v = c[:name] # the value of atom "name" in your deeply nested example. #=> "Meta description"
```

Of course you can break this down to one liner but I broke it down for you, so you get the process. You can go and get more and more information like a surgeon. Oddly as it sounds, the problem is that by simplifying it can also lead to complications So avoid one liner expressions.

Comment: You can ofcourse edit the above process to use it against a Struct. I used a map.

Answer (score 2):

For accessing deeply nested data, the [Access](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) module has some helpers that offer one solution:

```rb
get_in(landing_page.template.fields, [Access.at(1), :name])
#=> "Meta description"
```

Or, if I misunderstood what you were asking and you were trying to find an element in the list (and don't want to change your DB query), [Enum.find/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3) can be your friend:

```rb
Enum.find(template_fields, fn field -> field.name == "Meta description" end)
# or if you prefer a matching syntax
Enum.find(template_fields, &match?(%{name: "Meta description"}, &1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list has *exactly* 2 elements, then your pattern match would look something like this (where the name is assigned to the `name` variable in the capture). This works the same with simple maps as it does with structs:

```
iex> [_, %{name: name}] = [%{name: "Foo"}, %{name: "Meta description"}]

iex> name
"Meta description"
```

If your list might have 2 *or more* elements, then you'd need to adjust the shape of the match to include a `|` to signify the rest of the list (if present):

```
iex> [_, %{name: name} | _] = [%{name: "Foo"}, %{name: "Meta description"}, %{name: "other stuff"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you quite need pattern matching here...the `Enum` module offers a bunch of useful tools for handling data structures like maps/lists.

```
list = [
 %{name: "map1", attribute: "this is my attribute"},
 %{name: "map2", attribute: "this is my other attribute"}
]
map = Enum.find(list, fn x -> x.name == "map1" end)
```

`list` = list of maps 
`fn x -> x` = anonymous function seen also as `&(&1)` 
`x.name == "map1"` = condition to find the desired map. \

You can run this code in your mix console by running `iex -S mix`

My output is here:

```
iex(1)> list = [
...(1)>  %{name: "map1", attribute: "this is my attribute"},
...(1)>  %{name: "map2", attribute: "this is my other attribute"}
...(1)> ]
[
  %{attribute: "this is my attribute", name: "map1"},
  %{attribute: "this is my other attribute", name: "map2"}
]
iex(2)> map = Enum.find(list, fn x -> x.name == "map1" end)
%{attribute: "this is my attribute", name: "map1"}
iex(3)> map.name
"map1"
iex(4)> map.attribute
"this is my attribute"
```